# How do I delete environment domains and variables in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I can add new environments, but sometimes I no longer want domains I previously thought I needed.

I can't work out how to delete a variable within the environments or to delete that entire domain. I can delete environments so long as they aren't the last remaining one, but the last one, in order to delete that domain can't be deleted. Is there a special trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an environment variable or domain in Paw ([a quick screencast to explain better is available here](http://cl.ly/3t1W2z1H1F1V)):

- Go to the environment panel (Window menu > Environments – shortcut: ⌥⌘1)
- To delete a variable: hit the minus (-) button on the right side (only available if you have more than one variable)
- To delete a domain: click on the domain name pop up button (a blue button on the right side), and pick "Delete Domain"

[image: Delete environment domain in Paw]

---

*For previous versions of Paw:* You need to select the environment domain first, and then hit the delete key on your keyboard.

[image: Delete an environment domain in Paw]

*Note: this is going to change in the upcoming Paw 2.2, another UI, much easier to understand.*

Comment: Thanks. TBH, I'm so used to inconsistent and blatantly abysmal keyboard shortcut support in apps that I didn't even try that. I assumed that the menu item to delete it was disabled that it meant deleting it wasn't supported.

Comment: No, that's also mistake that Paw doesn't have a clear delete button. We're always trying to stick with OS X keyboard shortcuts and patterns as much as possible though...

Comment: I'm using 2.2.9 and I don't seem to be able to select the domain, how can I delete it in 2.2.x?

Comment: I've just updated my answer for newer versions of Paw. I hope it helps!